# What kind of hummingbird is this one?

Tags: identification, birds

Is it just a household variety, or something special?

They seem to like buddleia.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about an insect that's **affecting** your garden. Please see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-questions-about-birds-and-other-animals-in-your-garden-on-topic for our policy about these types of questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, that little guy is hard to photograph, isn't he? I don't think it is a hummingbird though. It looks like an insect to me. A gigantic one. In the next-to-last of your 7 photos (i.e. #6) you can see his tubular "sippy-tongue" poking into one of the flowers ... unless it is a shadow from one of his feelers. But Hummingbirds don't have tube-tongues *or* feelers. Also in photo #5 you can pretty much make out the "segments" on his insect abdomen. (Not sure what you call those.)

I think this is likely a Sphinx Moth or something similar. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphingidae) where it is referred to as a "Hawk Moth".

[image: Hawk Moth using its angled "proboscis"]

Amazing creatures! Wikipedia says they are often mistaken for hummingbirds.

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t a hummingbird, that’s actually a butterfly! Ok, a moth, to be precise: the [hummingbird hawk-moth (Macroglossum stellatarum).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hummingbird_hawk-moth)

But animal identification is not part of [our site’s scope](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so I have to flag it for migration to our sister site Biology SE.